# how to change css style from jquery

Tags: jquery

my style is here

```
#mybox{
display:none;
}
```

my web is here

```
<div id='mybox'>
...
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mybox").css("display","visible");
})
</script>
```

mybox don't show. How to show mybox ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `$("#mybox").show()` or `$("#mybox").css("display","block");`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#mybox').show();
```

or

```
$('#mybox').slideDown();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is display: block in stead of display visible:

```
<div id='mybox'>
...
</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mybox").css("display","block");
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the CSS with `display:none;` on an element you can trigger `.show()` and `.hide()` with jQuery on it! This is a jQuery default feature.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, "visible" isn't a valid value for the display attribute. Something like "block" or "inline" is. Secondly, don't set CSS directly like this. It's problematic. Instead use the [jQuery effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) for showing and hiding things (show/hide/toggle, slideUp/slideDown, fadeIn/fadeOut, etc):

```
$(function() {
  $("#mybox").show();
});
```

or alternatively use a class:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mybox").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

with:

```
div.visible { display: block; }
```

Comment: I find it useful to have an `hidden` class with `display: none;` - this can be applied to anything. Also, I think the `#mybox` css rule is stronger, so I'm not sure adding a class will show it.